# Python API client

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm creating a Python API client, after thinking and checking some open source Python clients I created this class, and I'm looking for any feedback (design, best practices...), this is an example URL of the API:

> ```
> https://www.api.com/collection/resource.json?userid=id&key=apikey&command=value
> ```

Here's my class using the [requests library](http://www.python-requests.org/):

```
import requests

class APIClient(object):
    """Creates an API client object

    :param userid: the API userid found in the control panel
    :param api_key: the API key found in the control panel Settings > API

    """
    def __init__(self, userid=None, api_key=None):
        # userid and api key sent with every request
        self.userid = userid
        self.key = api_key

        # the base production api url
        self.base_url = None

        # the sandbox api url
        self.test_url = None

        # boolean value to indicate which url to use
        self.testing = False

        # the error description if it occured
        self.error = None

    def request(self, method='GET', path=None, params=None):
        """Makes a request to the API with the given parameters

        :param method: the HTTP method to use
        :param path: the api path to request
        :param params: the parameters to be sent

        """
        # if we're testing use the sandbox url
        api_url = self.test_url if self.testing else self.base_url

        # add the authentication parameters (sent with every request)
        params.update({
            'userid': self.userid,
            'key': self.key
        })

        # the api request result
        result = None

        try:
            # send a request to the api server
            r = requests.request(
                    method = method,
                    url = api_url + path + '.json',
                    params = params,
                    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Python API Client'}
                )

            # raise an exception if status code is not 200
            if r.status_code is not 200:
                raise Exception
            else:
                result = r.json()
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            self.error = 'API connection error.'
        except requests.HTTPError:
            self.error = 'An HTTP error occurred.'
        except requests.Timeout:
            self.error = 'Request timed out.'
        except Exception:
            self.error = 'An unexpected error occurred.'

        return result
```

And here's a usage example:

```
from api import APIClient

# create the client
api = APIClient()

# authentication
api.userid = '123456'
api.key = '0tKk8fAyHTlUv'

# api urls
api.base_url = 'https://api.com/'
api.test_url = 'https://test.api.com/'

# api in testing mode
api.testing = True

# create a request
r = api.request(
            method = 'GET',
            # this will be appended to the base or test url and add .json at the end
            path = 'collection/resource',
            params = {
                'string-command': 'string',
                'list-command': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                'boolean-command': False
            }
        )

# how can I improve the way I get the API result and the error checking ?
# I currently use:
if api.error:
    print api.error
else:
    print r

# what about using something like ?:
if api.request.ok:
    print api.request.result
else:
    print api.request.error
```

My questions are:

- Is this a good design for use in a website, and is it safe for multiple requests?
- Should I store the API result in a property `api.result` instead of returning it when calling `api.request()`?
- How can I improve the way I get the API result? Is the second example better?
- How can I improve my code?

Comment: Look at this package: https://github.com/olegpidsadnyi/restart

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Python has a mechanism for handling exceptional situations, but you go to great lengths to suppress it: you catch all the exceptions that might result from your `request` method and replace them with a string in the `.error` property of the `APIClient` object.

   This has several problems.

   First, it needlessly complicates every API call. A caller can't just write:

   ```
   r = api.request(...) # might raise an exception
   do_something_with(r)
   ```

   allowing exceptions to pass up the call stack and so eventually appear on the console or in the log. Instead, they have to write:

   ```
   api.error = None # clear the old error, if any
   r = api.request(...) # might set api.error
   if api.error:
       # handle the error somehow
   else:
       do_something_with(r)
   ```

   This means that *every call to your API* needs to consider how to handle errors. What are programmers going to do? Well, mostly likely they will *raise* these errors:

   ```
   api.error = None # clear the old error, if any
   r = api.request(...) # might set api.error
   if api.error:
       raise MyError("API error: {}".format(api.error))
   else:
       do_something_with(r)
   ```

   So why bother suppressing these errors in your API in the first place?

   Second, you replace all exceptions that you don't recognize with `An unexpected error occurred.` So this makes it impossible to distinguish a `ProxyError` from a `TooManyRedirects` from an `SSLError`.

   Third, you lose information that was present in the exception objects. For example, an `SSLError` comes with a description of the problem, for example if the certificate doesn't match the domain, you'll get an error like this:

   ```
   requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'foo.com' doesn't match 'bar.com'
   ```

   This kind of information is vital in tracking down the cause of problems. But you replace this with `An unexpected error occurred` which is, frankly, useless.
2. If the status code is not 200, you:

   ```
   raise Exception
   ```

   Which has three problems: (i) you should raise an *instance* of an exception class, not the class itself; (ii) you should initialize the exception object with data that describes the exception; and (iii) the class [`Exception`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception) is supposed to be the *root of the class hierarchy* for "built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions" and user exceptions. You shouldn't raise `Exception` itself, but instead derive a specific exception class and raise an instance of that. So here you would need something like:

   ```
   class HTTPError(Exception): pass
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   raise HTTPError('Status code {}'.format(r.status_code))
   ```

   But in fact the `requests` module [already has a function](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) for doing this, so all you need to do is:

   ```
   r.raise_for_status()
   ```
3. Your interface for setting API parameters is to set them directly as properties of the API object:

   ```
   api = APIClient()
   api.userid = '123456'
   api.key = '0tKk8fAyHTlUv'
   api.base_url = 'https://api.com/'
   api.test_url = 'https://test.api.com/'
   api.testing = True
   ```

   It would be better for the constructor to take these as keyword arguments: (i) this allows the constructor to check that all required parameters have been set; (ii) parameter values can be checked (if possible); and (iii) the keyword argument mechanism is more flexible than object properties since you can pass a sets of keywords around in the form of a dictionary. So I would expect to write:

   ```
   api = APIClient(userid = '123456',
                   key = '0tKk8fAyHTlUv',
                   base_url = 'https://api.com/',
                   test_url = 'https://test.api.com/',
                   testing = True)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, but about the exceptions, I'm suppressing the errors because I wanted to show these messages only to the users of the website, I don't want to print all the errors although I want to log all of them, so should I keep suppressing the exceptions or call `api.request()` in a try/except block ?

Comment: Deciding how to handle exceptions should be up to the *caller* of the API, not up to the API itself.

Comment: Nice explanation, but i did't completely understood error handling part. Do you mean he should have only used one `raise HTTPError('Status code {}'.format(r.status_code))`

Comment: And what is the good way to deal with validation errors